# Jquery Closest Not working After Modal Toggle

Tags: jquery

I want remove any data with json. I use bootsrap modal for accepting remove. When accept remove jquery closest not working. How can ı fix it.

```html
        $('body').on('click', '.remove-button', function (event) {
            $('#modal').modal();
            return false;
        });
        $('body').on('click', '.remove', function (e) {
            $(this).closest(".pan").toggle(1000, function () {
                $(this).closest(".pan").remove(); // Not work
            });
            $('#modal').modal('toggle');
        });
```

.pan html

```html
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="panel panel-default pan">
        <div class="panel-heading text-capitalize text-weight-bold text-primary">@Html.Action("SenderName", "Messages", new { @Id = item.Sender }) - @item.Message.Date.ToMinifiedDate()</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @item.Message.Text
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="btn-group-xs text-center">
                @if (item.Status == MessageTypes.İletildi)
                {
                    <a class="btn btn-primary viewed"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Görüldü </a>
                }
                <a href="@Url.Action("SendMessage","Messages",new { @Id=item.Sender })" class="btn btn-default reply"><i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> Yanıtla</a>
                <a class="btn btn-default ban"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Şikayet</a>
                <a data-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-default remove-button"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Sil</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Modal Html

```html
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Mesaj Sil</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="text-capitalize">Mesaj <b class="text-primary">Silinecek</b> Onaylıyor Musunuz?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> İptal</button>
                <button id="removeButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat remove"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Evet Onayla</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Modal is working and modal toggle is working. But closest not working

Comment: Share the relevant HTML too.

Comment: Wouldn't the context of `this` change in the `.toggle()` callback?  It looks like you're trying to find the closest `.pan` to the `.pan` you're already on.  Shouldn't it just be `$(this).remove()`?  When you debug, what is `this`?

Comment: Im edit my code var panel = $(this).closest('.pan') and panel.toogle() its not work yet

Comment: @MuhammetBozdağ: It's not clear what you even meant to say in that last comment.  But I recommend you debug the `toggle()` callback function to see what the context of `this` is.  It seems likely to me that the context of `this` changes in that function and you'd have to adjust your DOM traversal to account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//Variable to hold the div tobe deleted
var DivToClose = null;
$('body').on('click', '.remove-button', function(event) {
  DivToClose = $(this).closest(".pan"); // assigning the div to this variable so as to delete it on confirmation.
  $('#modal').dialog();
  return false;
});
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
  DivToClose.toggle(1000, function() {
    DivToClose.remove(); // Not work
  });
  $('#modal').dialog('close');
});
$('body').on('click', '.cancel', function(e) {
  //remove the div reference, in case of cancel
  DivToClose = null;
  $('#modal').dialog('close');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default pan">
  <div class="panel-heading text-capitalize text-weight-bold text-primary">Pan A</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    XXXXX
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="btn-group-xs text-center">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-default reply"><i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> Yanıtla</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default ban"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Şikayet</a>
      <a data-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-default remove-button"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Remove</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="panel panel-default pan">
  <div class="panel-heading text-capitalize text-weight-bold text-primary">Pan B</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    XXXXX
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="btn-group-xs text-center">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-default reply"><i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> Yanıtla</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default ban"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Şikayet</a>
      <a data-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-default remove-button"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Remove</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Mesaj Sil</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="text-capitalize">Mesaj <b class="text-primary">Silinecek</b> Onaylıyor Musunuz?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat cancel" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Cancel</button>
        <button id="removeButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat remove"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Remove </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

I think your real problem is, Your div to be deleted and the original 'pan' div is in different places. One is not inside another. So you wont get the closest.
So you need to save the id to a hidden field or something, or should keep the reference of div in a script variable as i did in the example.

Comment: Thank you. İts work fine ı changed $('#modal').modal(); and $('#modal').modal('toggle');